# HEX calculation with python

Tags: python, hex

I used python 2.7, I know it's outdated, but for this example it's easier for me to understand. Let's say I have `0x70 / 3 = '0x25` in hex but I know that `25 + 25 + 25 = 6F` is not equal to `70`, which really should be `25 + 25 + 26 = 70`.

```
>>> a = hex(0x70 / 3)
>>> print a
0x25
>>> print hex(int(a, 16) * 2)
0x4a
>>> print hex(int(a, 16) * 3)
0x6f
>>> print hex(int(a, 16) * 3 + 1)
0x70
```

I want the python script to divide the `0x70` by `3` which gives `0x25` as a result and then self-check itself, in the way to take the `25`*`3` and fill the rest whatever the number is needed (in this case `+1` to make it equal to `70` again, so it's true. But it can't be hard-coded as different hex numbers won't always need to add the `+1` number. Basically I need to figure out how to script that it knows it is supposed to be `25 + 25 + 26 = 70` Because I will need those 3 numbers for later use. It's little hard for me to explain, so I apologize. Even better if the script could print what really `0x70 / 3` is that would make my life easier. For example:

```
a = hex(0x70 / 3)
print a
0x25
0x25
0x26
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed python 3, but maybe it works as well

```
hex(0x70 / 3)
```

prints for me an error, because it is a division with rest. 0x70 = 112 (in base 10) 112/3 = 37, period 3. The period 3 at the end can't be represented in hex (as far as I know)

if you use division without rest you will get 0x25

```
hex(0x70 // 3)
```

if you only calculate the rest you will get 0x01

```
hex(0x70 % 3)
```

is denominator fix or does it change? you can use the result or division without rest denominator-1 times and the last result you have to add the result of the rest division.